# Splitting up Datetime field on the fly in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, datepart

This is a query I wrote that I thought might be what I wanted. I think by looking at it you can see what I'm trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO tbTime
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATEPART(yyyy, ed),
    DATEPART(mm, ed),
    DATEPART(dd, ed),
    EntireDate AS ed
FROM test
```

I am basically copying the date field over from another table, but I want to split it up into year, month, and day fields on-the-fly. The above query won't work though:

`Invalid column name 'ed'.`

I am using SQL Server 2008, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't alias a field, then use that alias in other parts of the SELECT statement.

Try:

```
INSERT INTO tbTime
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATEPART(yyyy, EntireDate),
    DATEPART(mm, EntireDate),
    DATEPART(dd, EntireDate),
    EntireDate AS ed
FROM test
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I overlooked that.